# How do I map unmapped keys on a keyboard?

Tags: configuration, keyboard

My laptop's keyboard has keys that don't do anything when I press them.  How would I enable the keys, and add functionality to them?

For example, the mute key doesn't do anything at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xmodmap`. It's how I get my Zboard keys to work. **For actual keys not media keys.**

Comment: You may find `xev` helpful to find the key numbers.

Answer (score 3):

There's a keyboard shortcuts editor in System->Preferences.